# REST request in python certificate based authentication, working in SOAPUI

Tags: python, rest, ssl, client-certificates, truststore

I'm doing REST request against an https api server, its working in soapui using the configuration below, 
[image: soapui rest request is successful]

I've added the certificate on the SSL Settings>Keystore
[image: soapui ssl preferences]

the self-signed-keystore.jks has key pair that is trusted on the server and is being checked for each requests.  If the certs are valid the server will return a json

tried this in python using this code, its not working I'm getting an error on SSL

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xlocal',
>   port=8014): Max retries exceeded with url: //api/path/here (Caused by
>   SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
>   'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify
>   failed')],)",),))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://xlocal:8xxx/api/test/list"

#pem keys are exported from the jks using keytool explorer or 
#openssl pkcs12 -in soapui-keystore.p12  -nokeys -out soapuicert.pem
#openssl pkcs12 -in soapui-keystore.p12  -nodes -nocerts -out soapuikey.pem
NEW_CERT = r"C:\Users\myuser\self-signed-exported.cert.pem"
NEW_KEY = r"C:\Users\myuser\self-signed-exported.key.pem"

def main(argv):

    get = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, cert=(NEW_CERT, NEW_KEY))
    get2 = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, verify=NEW_CERT)

    print(get)
    print(get2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Its working on Java using this code, below.

```java
public void getforObject() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(Project.keystorePath)) {
            KeyStore keyStore = SSL.getKeyStore(fis, Project.keystorePassword);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = SSL.getSSLSocketFactory(keyStore, Project.keystorePassword, trustAllCerts);
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (hostname, session) -> true);
            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory).build();
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory);

            String forObject = restTemplate.getForObject(LIST_URL, String.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //SystemLogger.error("Error configuring ssl", e);
            throw new RuntimeException("Error: unable to configure ssl.", e);
        }
}

public class DummyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] paramArrayOfX509Certificate, String paramString)
                throws CertificateException {
        }
}
```

What seems to be the issue? Is there a better way to do this in python?

Comment: run `openssl s_client -connect xlocal -port 8xxx -debug` and see which certificate your service presents .. then inspect `self-signed-exported.cert.pem` with openssl to make sure the certificate CN matches

Comment: My cert contains the following CN=hsm,OU=sa,O=MyO,L=MyL,ST=VA,C=RU, the openssl s_client -debug returned a list which contains a match /C=RU/ST=VA/L=MyL/O=MyO/OU=sa/CN=hsm, the server is a tomcat 8 server which has a truststore containing that "hsm" entry.  Does this mean it has a match and request should be allowed right? In SOAP ui i'm using the JKS with the same cert as self-signed-exported.cert.pem and its working

Comment: if you run `openssl x509 -in self-signed-exported.cert.pem -text -noout`  that will show the same cert?  commented commando show that you output `soapuicert.pem` but in python code you use `self-signed-exported.cert.pem` is that correct

Comment: hi Yan, yes the certificates match. that's correct. Thou I have a new finding that I can run the code from python 3.6 vs 3.8 in linux and it return something.

Comment: You are getting a response with Python 3.8?  Correct response?

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: You seem to confuse server and client side certificate together. The SSL error 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed' is about server side certificate which means `requests` can't verify server.

Comment: `get2 = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, verify=NEW_CERT)` is wrong. `verify` argument needs a ca bundle or `True` to use the ca bundle came with `requests`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue by adding pem file in the request. You will need to create a pem file from p12 file with the following command.

openssl pkcs12 -in soapui-keystore.p12 -out self-signed-exported.pem

Code Snippet:

```
NEW_CERT = r"C:\Users\myuser\self-signed-exported.cert.pem"
NEW_KEY = r"C:\Users\myuser\self-signed-exported.key.pem"
PEM_FILE=r"C:\Users\myuser\self-signed-exported.pem"
get = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, verify=PEM_FILE, cert=(NEW_CERT, NEW_KEY))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is not your python code, but the certificate chain that you're supplying.

It's not sufficient to make available the certificate for your private key - you must supply the certificate for your key, plus every other certificate in a chain that terminates in a trusted certificate authority.

The openssl commands you're being asked to run will dump the certificate chain (which is generally public). That you can find your key's certificate in the pem file doesn't mean the certificate chain is complete or correct.